# XAML enlighten me with this binding commands

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

what are these? I am confused with the extra properties in "Binding"

```
{Binding Path=Customers, Source={StaticResource customerVM}, Mode=TwoWay}
{Binding Path=GetCustomersByNameCommand, Source={StaticResource customerVM}}
{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=tbName}
{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=LayoutRoot}
{Binding Path=TotalIncome, Mode=OneTime}
```

and more of those. What are those? I mean, where are they getting the Mode, Path, etc.. I don't understand.

The only thing I can understand is

```
{Binding ProperyName}
{StaticResource Anythinghere}
```

Comment: that is XAML man [Refer this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(v=vs.95).aspx)

[link2](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/silverlight-data-binding)

Comment: yes, I know it's XAML, but I am confused with those extra properties in "Binding"

Comment: @H.B. you can comment properly. Cussing is not necessary from someone learning. If you hate the question, then go away. If you can answer, then answer properly. Thanks for the link. It was helpful and exposed me to more properties in Binding and not just those Path and Mode

Comment: @JaysonRagasa: It's just a very short way of expressing my discontent with your apparent laziness.

Comment: Then saying "damn" is not necessary. You could just post the link

Comment: @JaysonRagasa Your question was far less necessary than his choice of words.  From my extremely brief overview of [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), your question violates 3 of the rules.  Your question isn't unique to an actual problem you are having and it isn't a real question. You just want someone to read the MSDN Reference to you because you are too lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding in XAML can be specified in many ways.

The simplest (shortcut) is

```
{Binding PropertyName}
```

This is equivalent to

```
{Binding Path=PropertyName}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
<Binding Path="PropertyName" />
```

`Binding` is actually a class with various properties such as Path, Source, Mode, etc.

More details on how to bind data in WPF can be found at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx#S2

Comment: It's very kind of you to help Jayson out, but maybe we shouldn't support him in not-reading the docs/manual...

Comment: Yes, but we could point him to the docs more politely perhaps? :)

Comment: Of course. I would never say that H.B.'s comment is the correct way to motivate someone doing in-front-research - I just think that we should encourage people more in self-learning and asking afterwards :)

Comment: We all deserve to learn, either from Docs or from someone. I have no shame on asking questions even if the dumbest question you ever heard.  Because asking question and the answer I got is the my quickest way to learn so I know what path to go

Comment: @JaysonRagasa: By doing that you are being lazy and take advantage of people's helpfulness, and to put it mildly that is not very nice.

Comment: I am thankful. I don't take advantage. I answer questions too and I answer in the most polite way.